# Monitor directory for changes without 3rd party packages

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

Many other questions is about this around StackOverflow. I haven't found any where the result doesn't use any 3rd party package.

The problem is that I'm using Hetzner and they want allow me to install any packages.

I can use PHP, Python, Java (think pretty much the standard collection)

> How to monitor a directory (recursive) for new files and get the references into another file.

I have tried something like this:

```
while true; do
    last=`cat log.txt`
    find "$UPLOAD_FOLDER"'/.' -type f > 'log.txt'
    now=`cat log.txt`

    diff -n <(echo "$last") <(echo "$now") >> 'queue.txt'

    sleep 60;
done;
```

But it's unreliable and it pollutes `queue.txt` with `d3a`,`b5a`, etc..

Comment: What can you use? Python? cron? etc.?

Comment: @AlG 
I can use PHP, Python, Java (think pretty much the standard collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use a marker file:

```
touch markerFile
while true
do
    find "$UPLOAD_FOLDER"'/.' -type f -newer markerFile >> 'queue.txt'
    touch markerFile
    sleep 60
done
```

Might be a slight race condition between the find and the touch?

A more complicated double buffering solution as suggested in the comments:

```
touch markerFileA
touch markerFileB
while true
do
    touch markerFileB
    find "$UPLOAD_FOLDER"'/.' -type f -newer markerFileA ! -newer markerFileB >> 'queue.txt'
    sleep 60
    touch markerFileA
    find "$UPLOAD_FOLDER"'/.' -type f -newer markerFileB ! -newer markerFileA >> 'queue.txt'
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: You could trade the false negatives for false positives by storing the  current time before the find then using touch -t

Comment: @cmh: Another way would be to alternate between two marker files, along the lines of double buffering. touch a; find -newer b ! -newer a; sleep; touch b; find -newer a ! -newer b; sleep

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` to remove the undesired output:

```
while :; do

    find "$UPLOAD_FOLDER/." -type f > "log1.txt"

    if [ -f "log2.txt" ]; then
        diff log1.txt log2.txt | sed '/^[^<]/d;s/^< //'

        fi

    mv "log1.txt" "log2.txt"

    sleep 60

done
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't install any packages... :(

Comment: @NULL Checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14161366/1006989), I modified it to get the desired output without installing packages